# Best Windows XSLT Processor for conditional PDF output?

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

Fellow Forum Members,
I have Army provided XSL stylesheets which have been coded in XSL 2.0 to generate XSL-FO output.  I would appreciated advice on a XSLT processor that can convert my XSL-FO stylesheet output into a PDF and also support some applicability I have coded in my XML files. In other words, I need an XSLT processor that offers a Windows 7 GUI that will enable me to organize all 330 XML files in the order I specify into a  single PDF publication. In addition, I need an XSLT processor that will filter out XML data I have tagged with applicability code. Does such a XSLT processor exist? I would really like to know an answer to this question because I need the ability to convert XML to PDF with the ability to filter out certain data in the PDF publication depending on whether or not certain XML attributes are present or not. Any opinions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Filtering out content based on some XML attributes is not within the scope of an XSL-FO Processor. XSL FO has no provisions in the language for logic decisions, you would do that in code or in the XSLT that produces the FO, not in the FO that is fed to an XSL FO engine. The process is XML+XSL->FO->FO Processor->PDF so you need an XSLT that does the filtering.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the post. Do you or anyone out there know of a XSLT processor that can perform both the filtering and also give me the ability to  combine 330 XML files into a single PDF? I have looked at Saxon, XRender, Xalan, Antenna House, and FOP with no success. I'm looking at XMLSpy and Oxygen XML next to see if these apps are the solution to my problem.  Thnx again

Comment: @Kevin actually the OP mentions that he is searching for a XSLT processor. I assume his question merely some terminology mixed up but that he is aware that he needs XSLT. That been said, though, Matrix: recommendations like that strictly speaking are off topic on SO.

Comment: @Matrix, it's two questions -- any XSLT processor can/should be able to do the filtering. XSL FO applications (and since I work for RenderX I can comment for that one) can combine 330 and even 10,000 or more into one output. This link as inspiration is not exactly what you want ... http://www.renderx.com/files/documents/RenderX_Large_Reports_Formatting.pdf that is formatting a huge XML, splitting it into many smaller ones and putting it back together in order. But it shows you can do it.

Comment: There's a tradition in SO of rejecting questions asking for advice on technology selection as being "opinion-based". I hate doing that, because I don't think that choosing the right technology is a subjective process; but it has to be said that it's rarely possible in the space available for the questioner to give enough information to allow an objective recommendation to be made.

Comment: @Matrix Firstly you need two things, an XSLT processor and an XSL-FO processor. Secondly, you tell us you have looked at various products "without success". These are the products that most of us would use for the job, so we can't make much progress unless we know why you found them unsuitable.

Comment: I use Antennahouse, this allows me to provide a single XSLT/FO template that contains conditions and formatting. I do't know how Antennahouse handles the XSLT internally, but I don't need to use a two-step process to generate my PDF.